# How to achieve a Html5 Textarea readonly with ng-bind-html without clickable link

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ng-bind-html

I have a Table with 2 Columns. One is just for "Comparing" the other one is to Edit/Format Text with TinyMce4. I want now that in the first row the Text is shown with `ng-bind-html` to show how its Formated but with the restriction that html links are formated and shown as that but not clickable/redirecting to the site.
Is there a way with `angularjs 1.5.x` or native `html5` ?
For example:
Iam getting Data like this:

```
Hello <b>World<b><a href="www.google.de">clickme</a>
```

It shall format it right

Hello **World** [clickme](https://www.google.de/)
But the link shall now not redirect or be clickable in the `readonly Textarea`

**Edit:**
For Clarification, I want a `Html5 Textarea` in which are html tags as `<bold><italic>` and so on are formatted. Through `ng-bind-html` or something else I dont care. The only exceptions should be `<a href=...>`. They are shouldn't be clickable or redirecting to the Link.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following:-

```
tinymce.init({
      selector: 'textarea',
      allow_unsafe_link_target: false
    });
```

Refernce Link which may help you:- https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/

Comment: Sorry if I wrote my Question a bit Confusing but I meant the Opposite. The Links are working. But I want it to NOT working. Not being clickable. Not redirecting. And this if possible in a Textarea. But the all the rest as <b><i><br> and so on shall be formatted and shown as that.

Comment: Ive Edited my Question. The Problem is not the TinyMce Editor but more that I want a Textarea which shows me the Text which I formatted with TinyMce. Everything except the Links :)